# How to encrypt and decrypt sms?

Tags: java-me

I need to create a small mobile application that will encrypt  the user selected sms to make it unreadable.after words user should be able to decrypt it only by entering proper key.we need to use J2me.Can anybody tell me how to start with it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible encrypt outgoing messages or receive an incoming encrypted sms using [WMA API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=205), however you should consider the following cases

1. Your application can receive the sms send to the designated ports
2. The Server/Aggregator that sends the sms should send the message in an encrypted format for which the client knows the key to decrypt.
3. Some phones might require signing of the build

However if you want to provide an interface to read the SMS that is in phone's default inbox, then it is either impossible or difficult to implement

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that most phones would allow you access to the users SMS. That would be a gross breach of privacy and the nightmares involved with it.

Although I have never used Java, I am sure it cant be that hard to encrypt and decrypt a string. A simple [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en-au&ei=p6tRSviVBKjg6gP4u7yABA&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&q=encrypt+decrypt+text+java+j2me&spell=1) search would offer some ways.

Then you would just need to provide a simple service to send short snippits of text between users. Im sure it wouldnt be that hard

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send encrypted messages or encrypt incoming ones? If the latter, this is pointless, because you can insert SIM card to another phone and there will be no security at all. Also, despite some devices J2ME can access received SMS messages, it won't allow you to modify it. If the first option (sending), you still have to fit encrypted message in 160 characters and it won't be possible on some devices.

Answer (score -1):

I get this WMkits SMS Encryption. It is a text messages encryption software for Windows Mobile phones. It can [encrypt and hide the SMS messages](http://www.wmkits.com/wmkits-sms-encryption-windows-mobile.html) (including existing SMS messages and future incoming/outgoing SMS messages) on windows mobile device.